# kafka-acls.sh does not provide a way to use prefix for topic and literal or all for group while giving permission for consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am unable to find a way in kafka-acls.sh to use prefix for topic name and literal or '*' for group while giving permission for consumer.

Is it possible or is design of kafka do not allow this? Do I need to write something directly to zookeeper for this?

Answer (score 2):

This feature was introduced recently (from version 2.0.0 I suppose - [JIRA link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6841)). [This link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-290%3A+Support+for+Prefixed+ACLs) talks about the feature in detail.

In short, a new switch was introduced with the name `--resource-pattern-type` and it can take values such as `PREFIXED`, `LITERAL`, `ANY` and `MATCH`.

Here's the source code for the `PatternType` class which has these details.

However, this seems like an evolving feature and I came across the following note in the comments section of [ResourcePattern.java](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/resource/ResourcePattern.java) class:

> The API for this class is still evolving and we may break
>   compatibility in minor releases, if necessary.

You could try using this switch with the 4 options to find out which one would suit your requirement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If am not wrong, isn't any and match is for list and delete only?

Comment: I guess I can work around by providing user with individual permission and using this prefix accordingly

Comment: Yes, I think you might just have to try out these possibilities to see which one will fit your requirement. Also, could you please acknowledge the answer? if this has pointed you in the right direction? :)